# How to read the values of the EDI via Xsl?

Tags: xslt

Below is the sample edi which i need to translate to an XML via XSL/XSLT only. I would like to know how to parse/read and retrieve the values from the EDI

```
UNB+UNOA:2+SENDER-ID+RECEIVER-ID+090211:0811+0001+++++GEKU'
UNH+0001+BAPLIE:D:95B:UN:SMDG20'
BGM++0001+9'
DTM+137:0902110811:201'
TDT+20+00018NB+++GEK:172:ZZZ+++47AVS:103:ZZZ:SALERNO PRIDE:IT'
LOC+5+ITCAG:139:6'
LOC+61+ITSAL:139:6'
DTM+132:090211:101'
DTM+178:0902111230:201'
DTM+136:0902112330:201'
RFF+VON:GKS01A'
LOC+147+0010112::5'
MEA+WT++KGM:22500'
LOC+9+ITCAG:139:6'
LOC+11+ITSAL:139:6'
RFF+BM:1'
EQD+CN+GEKS1504090+22G1+++5'
NAD+CA+GEK:172:ZZZ'
UNT+18+0001'
UNZ+1+0001'
```

Thanks in Advance. Basically need an XSL/XSLT

Comment: **1.** Can you use XSLT 2.0? **2.** Please provide the expected output and explain how to produce it from the given input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easiest/best to do this with **XSLT 2.0** using the [unparsed-text()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unparsed-text) function to load process the EDI content. With XSLT 2.0 you have advanced string functions and regex capabilities at your disposal.

Since your content is in a text file, you can use any XML (even the XSLT itself) as your input XML file and then in a template for the root node, load the text file and process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="edi" select="unparsed-text('edi.txt')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$edi"/>
        <!--do stuff with EDI text-->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you are using **XSLT 1.0**, you could create an XML "wrapper" document that includes the content of your EDI text through an entity reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE edi [
    <!ENTITY edi_text SYSTEM "edi.txt">  
]>
<edi>
    &edi_text;
</edi>
```

Then, parse and process the wrapper XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="edi">
        <!--do stuff with EDI text-->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Note: This could prove unreliable. If your EDI text contains any `&`
>   or `<` characters, you will get an XML parse error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parse something other than XML using XSLT 1.0. So it is impossible to parse EDI using XSLT 1.0

Comment: why? there are options to process csv to xml via xslt. similarly EDI is also a raw data. is that right? may be a difficult one to process, however it will work. please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: "*You cannot parse something other than XML using XSLT.*" That's true only with regard to XSLT 1.0. This doesn't mean that XSLT 2.0 or higher is the best tool to convert text to XML - but it is certainly possible.